# How much torque is needed?

Tags: torque

If we wanted to open gate with maximum force that man can apply at distance of 1m from pivoted joint.
So I want torque to determine motor and gearbox that can be used to automate gate.

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far. Is this a gate to a path or a gate across a railway line?

Comment: Do you want the motor to overcome a man who's trying to hold it shut, or to emulate a violent angry man shoving it as hard as he can? Be careful not kill children by bashing the gate into their heads at high speed. A man can control his application of force using intelligence that a motor can't. He will also be able to reliably apply an opposing force to slow the gate instead of bashing it into the wall at the end of its travel.

Comment: Thanks for your safety instructions. We will be careful about these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum push force for an adult male, is 818N according to NASA - https://msis.jsc.nasa.gov/sections/section04.htm#Figure%204.9.3-6

Applying this at a distance of 1m from the pivot, corresponds to a torque of:

$$T=F*d=818\text{ N} * 1\text{ m}=818\text{ Nm}$$

This is likely much more torque than is required to automate the gate, however - your calculations should be based on the mass and shape of the gate, and any speed requirements for opening time and/or acceleration, rather than on the force of a human.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Can you please tell me how to calculate torque on the basis of mass and acceleration if gate is weighing  3000 kg and is made of rectangular shape?

Comment: How fast does the gate need to open? I don’t have enough information

Comment: Gate should be opened in 4 sec through an angle of 80 degrees. Gate is folding type with two rectangular frames connected to each other. One of the frame is hinged to column while other is supported by pulley at the bottom placed on pipe and by bearing on the top.

Comment: Please make a diagram and update your question, rather than putting all the critical info buried in the comments!